# I get error when try to set overlap in QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a table with 4 rows.First 2 rows, column 0 must be spanned, last 2 rows, column 0 must be spanned too.
This is the piece of code I use but at the time of the second span I get

`QTableView :: setSpan: span cannot overlap`

```
    table.setRowCount(0)
    new_row = 0
    table.insertRow(new_row)
    table.setRowHeight(new_row, 20)
    table.setSpan(0, 0, 2, 1)     ### <------
    cell = QTableWidgetItem(str('AA'))
    table.setItem(new_row, 0, cell)
    a = 1
    while a <= 10:
        cell = QTableWidgetItem(str(a))
        table.setItem(new_row, a, cell)
        a += 1
    new_row += 1
    table.insertRow(new_row)
    table.setRowHeight(new_row, 20)
    
    a = 1
    while a <= 10:
        
        cell = QTableWidgetItem(str('CC'))
        table.setItem(new_row, a, cell)
        a += 1
    new_row += 1
    table.insertRow(new_row)
    table.setRowHeight(new_row, 20)
    table.setSpan(2, 0, 2, 1)     ### <------
    cell = QTableWidgetItem(str('BB'))
    table.setItem(new_row, 0, cell)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are *inserting* a row *within* the previously set span. Spanning is dynamic, not fixed: if you insert elements between cells that include the spanning, their span is expanded.

If the model already had 2 rows, setting a 2-row span would make the first row span to the second one. Now, consider: what you should happen if you *inserted* a row between the first and the second? You would expect that the spanning should then *extend* to include all three rows, wouldn't you?

When you create the first row and set the first span, although there is only one row, the internal "span collection" will still keep that reference. When you insert a row at index 1 (meaning, between 0 and 1), the span is expanded as explained before: including rows 0 to 2, the first three rows. And that's even if there are still only two rows.

The error, then, comes from the fact that you're finally adding that third row (which is included in the span above), and when you try to set the second span, it won't work because it would overlap the previous one, because you want it to start from the third row.

The solution is simple: only set spans as soon as their rows or columns exist, not before.

In your case, move the first `setSpan()` *after* adding the second row. Consequentially, you should do the same for the second `setSpan()` only when its "spanned" rows are actually added (as right now, you're doing the same mistake).